# Display data from two arrays having one common point

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have two arrays.
The first one is about exchange-rate and the display in my console is like this :

```json
{
  "exchange_rate": [
    {
      "id": "978",
      "start_dateTime": "2021-08-01 07:35:02",
      "target_value": "1.00000",
      "currency_value_euro": "0.84097",
      "currency_value_dollar_us": "1.00000",
      "id_currency": "1",
      "currency": "Dollar am\u00e9ricain",
      "currency_symbol": "$US"
    },
    {
      "id": "980",
      "start_dateTime": "2021-08-01 07:35:02",
      "target_value": "1.00000",
      "currency_value_euro": "1.17454",
      "currency_value_dollar_us": "0.71600",
      "id_currency": "2",
      "currency": "Livre sterling",
      "currency_symbol": "\u00a3"
    }
  ]
}
```

These data came from the database and I can display it by choosing particular dates with jQuery.

The second array contains only id_currency which in my console is like this : `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5` 
On my website, I want to be able to  display specific exchange rate by specific currency and dates.
And here my problem appears, I can't find the way to loop on the first array, and loop again inside, on the second array and compare both like if first array has id_currency 1 and second array has id_currency 1 then display the complete line from first array.

I've tried several things but nothing works, at last i've tried this :

```
foreach ($res as $row){
            $idBDD = $row['id_currency'];
            $symbolBDD = $row['currency_symbol'];
            echo $idBDD;
            echo $symbolBDD;
            //var_dump($row);
            /*foreach ($arr as $line){
                $idCheckbox = $line;
                echo $idCheckbox;
            }
            if ($idBDD == $idCheckbox){
                echo 'fine';
            }
            */
        }
```

I'll be grateful for your help

Comment: What do you mean by this sentence `compare both like if first array has id_currency 1 and second array has id_currency 1 then display the complete line from first array.` ? How do you compare id_currency and what do you mean display the complete line?

Comment: The first array ['exchange_rate'] contains an array for each currency. Each currency has an id, start_datetime, id_currency etc.

Comment: Then, what do you need to compare and after compare, what do you want to do with it?

Comment: I can display the first by choosing specific dates. The second array contains id_currency of specific currencies (chose with checkboxes), I want to "compare" if in the second array I've chose Euro (for example) which has 1 for id_currency, I look into [exchange_rate] array and display arrays(containing informations (date, symbol etc) that was my complete line in my head) which have id_currency 1. if both arrays has same id_currency I want to display corresponding informations from the first array.

Comment: Do you mean if there is any common fields among arrays, display all the common fields?

Comment: Yes that's I would like to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do it like this, of course if you're inside the loop, you won't need to put indices.

read more array_diff()
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-diff.php

```
$array = [
    "exchange_rate" => [
        [
            "id" => "978",
            "start_dateTime" =>  "2021-08-01 07:35:02",
            "target_value"=>  "1.00000",
            "currency_value_euro"=>  "0.84097",
            "currency_value_dollar_us"=>  "1.00000",
            "id_currency"=>  "1",
            "currency"=>  "Dollar am\u00e9ricain",
            "currency_symbol" =>  "US"
        ],[
            "id"=>  "980",
            "start_dateTime"=>  "2021-08-01 07=> 35=> 02",
            "target_value"=>  "1.00000",
            "currency_value_euro"=>  "1.17454",
            "currency_value_dollar_us"=>  "0.71600",
            "id_currency"=>  "2",
            "currency"=>  "Livre sterling",
            "currency_symbol"=>  "\u00a3"
        ]
    ]
];

$array1 = $array['exchange_rate'][0];
$array2 = $array['exchange_rate'][1];

$result = array_diff( $array1,  $array2);

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the array with `$res["exchange_rate"]` and loop through it then.

```php
<?php
$res = [
    "exchange_rate" => [
        [
            "id" => "978",
            "start_dateTime" => "2021-08-01 07:35:02",
            "target_value" => "1.00000",
            "currency_value_euro" => "0.84097",
            "currency_value_dollar_us" => "1.00000",
            "id_currency" => "1",
            "currency" => "Dollar américain",
            "currency_symbol" => "\$US"
        ],
        [
            "id" => "980",
            "start_dateTime" => "2021-08-01 07:35:02",
            "target_value" => "1.00000",
            "currency_value_euro" => "1.17454",
            "currency_value_dollar_us" => "0.71600",
            "id_currency" => "2",
            "currency" => "Livre sterling",
            "currency_symbol" => "£"
        ]
    ]
];

$output = null;

foreach ($res["exchange_rate"] as $row) {
    if (!isset($output)) {
        $output = $row;
    }
    $output = array_intersect_assoc($output, $row);
}

var_dump($output);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I've tried your demo and it works but then how do you compare the id_currency of the ['exchange_rate'] array and id_currency from the second array ? It's the second array that must determined which line of the exchange_rate array should display .. (Sorry if I'm not clear in my explanations)

Comment: @grollote, I updated my answer. is this what you want? I only get all the common fields among all arrays.

Comment: @grollote, if this answer help or you think it is useful. Please accept it, so it may help people with the same issue in the future.